# Normalization: is it worth it for small words (more queries needed)?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table (hundreds of thousands of rows) where my users store their game results.  In a row, alongside with 6 results, I store the "object" they used while playing and the "technique" they used.  In my situation, there are about 30 possible different objects and 10 possible different techniques.  Each object and technique is one word long.

According to normalization, I would create an "object" and a "technique" table where each object and technique are given a unique ID and then use a foreign key to link them from my big table where all results are listed. So instead of having the object's name in the big table, I would have a number from 1-30.

My users will do many queries in the big table to search for 
results `WHERE object = "objectname" AND technique = "techniquename"`.  If I use foreign keys, I will need 3 queries instead of one (to first get the objectID and techniqueID and finally search the results that match in the big table).

So is it worth it considering that the database will receive 3 times more queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not normally have 3 queries, you would have one query that joined three tables. As long as you have working indices on all the foreign keys, the difference in speed is negligible, and the gain in robustness is priceless (there is also better space efficiency, but today disks are cheap, so this is of secondary interest).

```
SELECT *
FROM hundreds_of_thousands R
JOIN techniques T ON T.id = R.technique_id
JOIN objects O ON O.id = R.object_id
WHERE O.name = "objectname"
  AND T.name = "techniquename"
```